# How can I get rid of those cloudflare captchas? it's annoying

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

How can I get rid of those cloudflare captchas? i think I wont even open up cloudflare websites anymore

Answer (score 0):

The CloudFlare *itself* has no problem with it: take a look at the [corresponding post in their blog](https://blog.cloudflare.com/the-trouble-with-tor/), so it's technically an issue with the presets for the particular site. You have to complete the captcha - and use the site. Yes - it's not a pleasant deed, when you see these sites one-by-one, but sadly - No, there's nothing you can do as a website client